# Consequence of Overheated Voltage Regulator

Tags: voltage-regulator

Would voltage regulator shut down itself if it is overheated? From the datasheet, it mentioned that there is thermal shutdown circuit in it, so if I am not wrong it should be able to cut off itself it is overheated.

I am asking this because I had a voltage regulator which was connected to power supply without any load. The moment I turned on the power supply, I heard something explode. After that, the voltage regulator would just give me whatever supplied voltage that I feed into it.

Comment: Which voltage regulator? They don't all have the same behaviour. Internal thermal shutdown isn't something you want to be relying on in the first place. As for your second paragraph, show a schematic of what you did, otherwise people can only guess the reason for what happened.

Comment: A linear regulator with no load should not overheat, so its thermal shutdown circuit (if it has one) shouldn't come into play.

Comment: The model is L1117-33 from Texas Instrument (3.3V LDO Regulator)

Comment: The circuit should be alright.. After I replaced the regulator and install a heatsink for it. The regulator managed to give me a constant 3.3v output.

Comment: @Daozui I'm seriously glad to hear everything is okay. :) You did make me chuckle for a moment, though. It almost sounded like a question asking, "I wonder if my regulator has a thermal shutdown because I heard a loud bang and saw my regulator smoking and burning and now it just gives me whatever I feed into it." Which, of course, made me think of a datasheet saying, "Automatic thermal shutdown is handled internally by fusing the input to the output and is indicated by a loud sound followed by a rising puff of smoke."

Comment: Current has to flow in a loop, trace back your steps, bridged solder joints, incorrect component orientation, unfriendly load, etc...

Answer (score 1):

> Would voltage regulator shut down itself if it is overheated?

If it has a thermal shutdown, then yes it will. Most don't so if you get into a thermal runaway and exceed the absolute maximum temperature your regulator will die.

> The moment I turned on the power supply, I heard something explode.
>   After that, the voltage regulator would just give me whatever supplied
>   voltage that I feed into it.

If you heard it pop, odds are you did something wrong, the most likely scenario is the pins were not connected correctly. Get a new one, triple check the pins, the orientation, the package and the part number and the source (the place you bought it from, bad sources can sell mislabeled or fake parts.)

Answer (score 0):

Protection devices are designed for normal operation.

That means when the circuit is designed properly the protection mechanisms will keep the thing from failing when some factor wanders out of specification.

Thermal protection in particular is designed to shut the unit down should the temperature exceed some limit and, if designed properly, should normally only come into play if the ambient air temperature plus the heat due to the load takes the device over that limiting value. Proper design should prevent the latter, ambient temperature you can't do much about.

Voltage regulators can die, or explode, due to many reasons. Over voltage at the input, instantaneous over-current, voltage spikes, back-driving, are just a few.

If your device exploded, check your build, and check your design against the manufacturer's specification data and see what you did wrong.